# Possible to make maven build include .class files from dependencies

Tags: java, maven

It's become quite a drag to manually drag the contents of each .jar my API depends on into my compiled .jar so it will work properly, and I was wondering if there was any functionality for maven to automatically extract the .class files of the dependencies and add them to the .jar file it compiles, this would make life so much simpler, especially when doing numerous builds for testing. When I have to open my .jar as a .zip, and drop in the sources 5-10 times a minute when trying to fix a bug, it gets really annoying, really quickly.

I've done quite a bit of googling on this, but I've found nothing, just a bunch of links explaining how to add dependencies to maven, but nothing on adding the contents of a dependency to a maven build.

Comment: Take a look at maven shade plugin

Answer (score 2):

Use the maven shade plugin to create an "Uber" Jar that contains the dependencies defined in the pom within your JAR

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html

Comment: Always worth taking the time to get your build to be a one step process