# Maven shade plugin not pushing dependencies to .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206914/possible-to-make-maven-build-include-class-files-from-dependencies) earlier, that was asking how to have maven automatically compile my dependencies sources into my build's .jar, and I was directed to the [Maven Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin, however I can't seem to get it to work. The build hasn't change at all, I've already cleaned->updated-> rebuilt the project a few times.

**Here's my pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>net.example.net</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-framework</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>exampleFramework</name>
      <description>http://examplenet/</description>
      <url>http://example.net/</url>
      <organization>
        <name>example</name>
        <url>http://example.net/</url>
      </organization>
      <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.24.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the results of the compilation are

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-03T10:22:45-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/93M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the file size is about 80kb, it's about 5mb with the dependencies added (Which I've had to do manually and it's annoying)

**EDIT: Please note that eclipse put the `<plugin>` outside of the `<pluginManagement>`, I thought this could have been the issue and moved it manually, but it didn't change anything**

Comment: You should read [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) your pom is missing the "configuration part"

Comment: @RC - Been there, done that, no results. I've tried numerous different 'routes' as-well. I'll change my pom back to how the 'usage' page (Which I basically linked to in my question) shows the implementation.

Comment: Question modified, producing the same result./

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html --- I don't understand which one of these would be required, either.

Comment: None, those are advanced use. The pom in you question looks good to me, you should try on the command line: `mvn clean package` and if that produce a jar with deps then your question is how to make eclipse run maven package goal after a build

Comment: I'm using eclipse directly for handling maven, I can't execute mvn commands on the command line. `mvn`is not recognized as an internal or external command, also, in my run configurations in eclipse I have "package" specified as the goal.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026248/run-mvn-package-on-build-project-in-eclipse

Comment: @RC - Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66143/discussion-between-rc-and-christian-tucker).

Comment: Silimar to `<dependencyManagement>` vs `<dependencies>`, `<pluginManagement>` does not really declare a plugin to run.  It should be under `project->build->plugins->plugin` instead of `project->build->pluginManagement->plugins->plugin`